# Hibernate help me write query

Tags: java, database, hibernate

Im making an email client in java. When user creates mail with attachment(document), it saves all the data about email message in database but in multiple tables, like attachement title in Document_table.title, number of message in msgnumber.num, date in msgnumber.date, name of sender in Official_Person.name and OfficialPerson.secondname.
How do i retrieve all this data and display it (im using Jtable for this)? I know how to get data if it saved in one table but not multiple. please help me.

one format has many documnets.

DOCUMENT:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="DOCUMENT"
    ,schema="Default"
)
public class Document implements java.io.Serializable {

@ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "FormatID")
private Format format;
    @Id
    @Column(name = "DocumentID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private int documentId;
```

FORMAT :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="FORMAT"
    ,schema="Default"
)
public class Format implements java.io.Serializable {


    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "FormatID")
    private Set<Document> documents = new HashSet();

    @Id
    @Column(name = "FormatID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private int formatId;
```

format.hbm

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="entity2.Format" table="FORMAT">
        <id name="formatId" type="int">
            <column name="FormatID" length="2000000000" />
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>
                <set name="documents" table="DOCUMENT"
                inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
            <key>
                <column name="FormatID" not-null="true" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="entity2.Document" />
        </set>
```

document.hbm

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="entity2.Document" table="DOCUMENT">
        <id name="documentId" type="int">
            <column name="DocumentID" length="2000000000" />
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>

        <many-to-one name="format" class="entity2.Format" fetch="select">
            <column name="FormatID" not-null="true" />
        </many-to-one>
```

i want to retrieve all documents for format 1:

```
Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        Format f = (Format) session.get(Format.class, 1);
System.out.println(f.getName());
        System.out.println(f.getDocuments());
```

documents is empty? where am i wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you define a relationship between classes, for example:

```
class Person {    
   @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL,
              fetch= FetchType.EAGER)
   private Set<Email> emails = new HashSet();

   // getters/setters and some other attributes are not shown
```

When you read an object from the database, you will get another object that has a relationship with it automatically.

```
Session s = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
Person p = (Person) s.get(Person.class, 1);
s.close();

System.out.println(p.getName());
System.out.println(p.getEmails());
```

The following is an example of bidirectional one to one relationship.

```
class Person {
    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private Address address;


class Address {
    @OneToOne(mappedBy=”address”)
    private Person person
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. But what if my objects dont have direct relation? they connected through proxy tables(objects) .

Comment: I don't know about proxy table.

Comment: I mean they dont have direct relation through ids

Comment: Can you give me an example of the relationship?

Comment: Table Document has FK ValidatorID, table VAlidator has fk OrganizationID. I need to select given Organization and all its Documents. If you could give  an example it would help me so much!

Comment: This is one to one relationship that can navigate back and forth.  Please see the edited answer.

Comment: System.out.println(p.getEmails()); p.getMails is empty. Do i need to add something in hbm files or something?

Comment: Try `@OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch= FetchType.EAGER)`

Comment: but i need i one to many relation, could you describe what  i need to do to make this work? thanks in advance

Comment: public class Person {
    @OneToMany(cascade= CascadeType.ALL, 
                           fetch= FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "person_id")
    private Set<Address> addresses = new HashSet<Address>();

public class Address {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="person_id")
    private Person person;

Answer (score 1):

You just write the query using a select statement for all of the values you wish to retrieve. Hibernate will return an array with those values in it with the indices in the same order as your select statement.

SELECT 
FROM Person AS P, Address AS A, Order AS O, User AS U
WHERE P.id = 5
  AND A.personId = P.id
  AND O.personId = P.id
  AND U.personId = P.id

This will return an array containing {person, address, List, User}

Comment: Could you please provide example for four tables? It would really help. Thanks in advance

Comment: The best way to say thank you is to up vote my answer or mark it as the solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate is an ORM tool - the "O" stands for "object".  Start with an Email object that maps to your table and columns.  Then use HQL to query for Email instances that meet a particular restriction.

JTable or web page are display issues that are separate from the manner in which you query for objects.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I dont know how to write hql query for multiple tables(objects). Or do i need to create a proxy object? I dont have an Email object. al data stored in different tables.

Comment: Yes, you have tables, but those are the "R" side of ORM.  If you don't have objects, you shouldn't be using Hibernate.  Just go with straight JDBC and SQL.

Comment: Thanks for responce. I mean i have my message data spread across multiple classes and dont have expirience retrieving it form more than 2 objects. And my tables dont have direct connections through ids.

Comment: Both your object and relational models sound like hopeless messes.  I'd forget about both.  Just try JDBC and SQL.